# IllegalArgumentException : Comparison method violates it's general contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Following is my Comparator :

```
class CostComparator implements Comparator<Index> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Index itemIndex1, Index itemIndex2) {
    return Grid[itemIndex1.x][itemIndex1.y].cost >
        Grid[itemIndex2.x][itemIndex2.y].cost ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

The Grid above is a 2D array of item indexes. I have some memory considerations because of which I am storing indices instead of items in the Grid.

The compare method takes the indices and compares the cost of the Items at those indices.

Comment: You forgot to handle the `==` case ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, it violates the comparison if two indexes have the same cost. It *should* return 0, but it will return -1. As a *trivial* violation, that means that `compare(index, index)` will always return -1, when it *must* return 0.

It's really easy to fix though:

```
return Integer.compare(Grid[itemIndex1.x][itemIndex1.y].cost,
    Grid[itemIndex2.x][itemIndex2.y].cost);
```

(Change `Integer` to whatever the type of `cost` is.)

Comment: For learning purpose, I'm trying to figure out what is better in your answer than mine that worth 4 vs 1 votes ? :). We actually posted both at the same time, so I doubt it's a matter of times. We both had 0 votes when I posted

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Mine was posted over a minute before yours. It's entirely possible that a bunch of people had loaded the page when my answer was visible, but yours wasn't - they may have *cast* their upvote after you posted your answer, but without seeing it. I'd also say my answer is a little clearer about the violation.

Comment: Oh well, I did not realize yours was posted so long before.. Maybe just a matter of page load as you say. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the case where both values are `equals`

```
return Grid[itemIndex1.x][itemIndex1.y].cost >
        Grid[itemIndex2.x][itemIndex2.y].cost ? 1 : -1;
```

Should be changed to

```
return Integer.compare(Grid[itemIndex1.x][itemIndex1.y].cost,
    Grid[itemIndex2.x][itemIndex2.y].cost);
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) for more information on how to implement.

Also, you might want to check for possible `null` values before doing the comparison.